# How to remove the space between cols using no-gutter

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, gutter

I used the following code for set two cols but these is a space between them. how to remove the space. As you see im using "no-gutter".

see the pic:
https://ibb.co/80zTh60

```
<section id="incubator">
    <div class="overlay">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 incu-color rebeccapurple">

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 incu-img">
            <img src="img/Facility/dedicated.jpg" alt="De">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>      
</section>
```

```
#incubator{
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
.incu-color{
    height: 400px;
}
.incu-color.rebeccapurple{
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
.incu-img img{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: -100px;
    right: 0;
    height: 500px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.incu-text{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: darkorchid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the padding from col-md-6 that bootstrap brings by default.

You can easly do that by defining a new class:

```
.nopadding {
    padding: 0 !important;
 }
```

And applying it to the elements that contain col-md-6 class. Or, as pointed in the comments, if you are using bootstrap 4, use the already existing class **p-0**.

HTML:

```
     <section id="incubator">
    <div class="overlay">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 incu-color rebeccapurple nopadding">

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 incu-img nopadding">
            <img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg" alt="De">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>      
</section>
```

Comment: Or, use the provided BS4 classes: `p-0` & `m-0`

Comment: Yeap, that's totally true! (no need for m-0 in this case)

Comment: In that case, it's because your image hasn't  "widht:100%" set, as I don't have access to it, I can't test, but it looks the case, try setting it and tell the outcome :)

Comment: the image has had "max-width=100%". i changed it to width=100% and it works. Thanks.